# How do I Write-Progress in Powershell based on events from object?

Tags: multithreading, powershell, events

I have a small C# file that defines a `SumCalculator` class. It has a method `CalculateSum(int totalSteps)` that calculates the sum of numbers from 1 to `totalSteps` and raises a `CalculationStep` event returning arguments of `LongOperationArgs` class on each consecutive number. I want to create an instance of the `Calculator` class in my PowerShell 5.0 script and report the calculation progress using `Write-Progress` cmdlet. Here's the code:

```
    $csharpSource = @'
    using System;
    namespace Test
    {
        public class LongOperationArgs : EventArgs  {
            public int TotalSteps { get; private set; }
            public int CurrentStep { get; private set; }
            public LongOperationArgs(int totalSteps, int currentStep) {
                TotalSteps = totalSteps;
                CurrentStep = currentStep;
            }
        }
        public class SumCalculator {
            public event EventHandler<LongOperationArgs> CalculationStep;
            private void OnCalculationStep(LongOperationArgs e) {
                EventHandler<LongOperationArgs> handler = CalculationStep;
                if (handler != null) {
                    handler(this, e);
                }
            }

            public int CalculateSum(int totalSteps) {
                var sum = 0;
                for(var i = 1; i <= totalSteps; i++) {
                    sum += i;
                    OnCalculationStep(new LongOperationArgs(totalSteps, i));
                }
                return sum;
            }
        }
    }
    '@
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition "$csharpSource"

    $calculator = New-Object Test.SumCalculator
    $action =
    {
        $jobId = 1;
        $jobActivity = "Calculating...";
        if ($EventArgs.CurrentStep -eq $EventArgs.TotalSteps)
        {
            Write-Progress -Id $jobId -Activity $jobActivity -Completed;
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Progress -Id $jobId -Activity $jobActivity -Status "Step $($EventArgs.CurrentStep) of $($EventArgs.TotalSteps)" -PercentComplete ($EventArgs.CurrentStep / $EventArgs.TotalSteps * 100);
        }
    }
    $bar = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $calculator -EventName "CalculationStep" -Action $action
    $calculator.CalculateSum(100);
```

My problem is that Powershell runs `CalculateSum()` and `Write-Progress` in the same thread. So first `CalculateSum()` runs to completion, and only then `Write-Progress` starts reporting progress. My first response was to change the last line of my script from

```
    $calculator.CalculateSum(100);
```

to

```
    $job = Start-Job { $calculator.CalculateSum(100); }
```

but that caused the progress to stop being reported (`Write-Progress` likely wants events from `$calculator` to be thrown in the same thread). Is there any way to make `Write-Progress` respond to `$calculator` events when calculation is done in a different thread?